# How to optimize below multiple strncmp?

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to check the string to see it matches any of the prefixes. The number of prefixes to be compared will increase in the future. So I have concern on the performance of code like below. What are the options to make it run faster when there are lots of strings need to be checked?

```
int checkString(const char *name)
{
    if(!name) return 0;

    if(strncmp(name, "AE_", 3) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                              
    if(strncmp(name, "AEDZ_", 5) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                            
    if(strncmp(name, "EDPZ_", 5) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                            
    if(strncmp(name, "EFAN_", 5) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                            
    if(strncmp(name, "E_GCA", 5 ) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "EFFAN_", 6) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "EPDPZ_", 6) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "EDDPZ_", 6) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "ECADF_", 6) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "EPCEA_", 6) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "CFEXXX_", 7) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                          
    if(strncmp(name, "IFEXX_", 7) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                           
    if(strncmp(name, "EINFFAN_", 8) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                         
    if(strncmp(name, "NXXEFAN_", 8) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                         
    if(strncmp(name, "ENAEAZY_", 8) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                         
    if(strncmp(name, "EYYYYYY_", 8) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                         
    if(strncmp(name, "ENEOENUE_", 9) == 0 ) return 1;                                                                        
    /*
    more strncmp to be added.
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of techniques!! You could start here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: This is clearly C, not C++ (C++ would use `std::string` so it doesn't need to use `strncmp()`). Please don't use the C++ tag for C questions.

Comment: keep prefixes in an array and loop into array while checking string.

Comment: If you're going to have very many of them, a B-tree might be a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be the solution.

Comment: How many strings, and how many lookups? Hash table, array with binary search, trie - many options.

Comment: Firstly, "best" requires that you provide a precise description of what is better, otherwise it's just asking for opinions. That said, the simplest improvement to your code is a loop. Please, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the options to make it run faster when there are lots of strings need to be checked?

If the `n` prefixes were sorted, then at most `log2(n)` compares would be needed.  Code could use `bsearch()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *prefix[] = {"AE_", "AEDZ_", "CFEXXX_", "ECADF_", "EDDPZ_",
    "EDPZ_", "EFAN_", "EFFAN_", "EINFFAN_", "ENAEAZY_", "ENEOENUE_", "EPCEA_",
    "EPDPZ_", "EYYYYYY_", "E_GCA",  "IFEXX_", "NXXEFAN_"};

int cmp(const void *key, const void *element) {
  const char *k = key;
  const char *e = *(const char **) element;
  size_t elen = strlen(e);
  printf("strncmp(%s,%s,%zu)\n", k,e,elen);
  return strncmp(k, e, elen);
}

void test(const char *key) {
  printf("Search for <%s>\n", key);
  size_t n = sizeof prefix/sizeof prefix[0];
  const char **s = bsearch(key, prefix, n, sizeof prefix[0], cmp);
  if (s) {
    printf("Found <%s>\n", *s);
  } else {
    printf("Not Found\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  test("E_GC");
  test("E_GCA");
  test("E_GCA_");
}
```

Output

```
Search for <E_GC>
strncmp(E_GC,EINFFAN_,8)
strncmp(E_GC,EYYYYYY_,8)
strncmp(E_GC,IFEXX_,6)
strncmp(E_GC,E_GCA,5)
Not Found
Search for <E_GCA>
strncmp(E_GCA,EINFFAN_,8)
strncmp(E_GCA,EYYYYYY_,8)
strncmp(E_GCA,IFEXX_,6)
strncmp(E_GCA,E_GCA,5)
Found <E_GCA>
Search for <E_GCA_>
strncmp(E_GCA_,EINFFAN_,8)
strncmp(E_GCA_,EYYYYYY_,8)
strncmp(E_GCA_,IFEXX_,6)
strncmp(E_GCA_,E_GCA,5)
Found <E_GCA>
```

Comment: One caveat: Code needs to insure the `prefix[]` array is sorted correctly.

Comment: This is a good solution, but more work and worse big-O (log n vs 1) than regex.

Answer (score 3):

One-time, ahead-of-time setup:

```
regex_t re;
regcomp(&re, "^(AE_|AEDZ|_EDPZ_|EFAN_|E_GCA|" /*...*/ ")", REG_EXTENDED);
```

To check:

```
return regexec(&re, name, 0, 0, 0) == 0;
```

On any good regex implementation, the `regcomp` will compile the regex to a DFA that executes in a number of steps bounded by the length of the longest prefix.

Comment: On my computer, using C++11's `std::regex` is two _orders of magnitude_ slower than POSIX regex, even with `extended`, `optimize`, and `nosubs` set.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Which C++ stdlib? GCC's libstdc++? LLVM's libc++? MSVC? Something else? In any case I'm not sure how C++ has any relation to the question.

Comment: Sorry, should have stated GCC 8.2.1's libstdc++. I wondered what your solution would look like if I wrote it in C++11 (for portability to non-POSIX systems). I figure other people who have a similar question would be interested in knowing that libstdc++ is not necessarily a "good regex implementation".

Comment: @AlexReinking: Yes. There's a comment in `include/bits/regex_executor.tcc`'s `_M_handle_accept` that suggests they're using an extremely slow approach to finding the longest match for `|` in POSIX BRE/ERE. That might be the problem. Or it might be using the backtracking engine for some non-reason.

Answer (score -2):

If the prefixes don't change and are only added and you declare a constant for the quantity of prefixes you have, you could loop using `strstr`:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#define N_STRINGS 17

int checkString(const char *name);

const char *subStrings[N_STRINGS];

int main() {

    subStrings[0] = "AE_";
    subStrings[1] = "AEDZ_";
    subStrings[2] = "EDPZ_";
    subStrings[3] = "EFAN_";
    subStrings[4] = "E_GCA";
    subStrings[5] = "EFFAN_";
    subStrings[6] = "EPDPZ_";
    subStrings[7] = "EDDPZ_";
    subStrings[8] = "ECADF_";
    subStrings[9] = "EPCEA_";;
    subStrings[10] = "CFEXXX_";
    subStrings[11] = "IFEXX_";
    subStrings[12] = "EINFFAN_";
    subStrings[13] = "NXXEFAN_";
    subStrings[14] = "ENAEAZY_";
    subStrings[15] = "EYYYYYY_";
    subStrings[16] = "ENEOENUE_";

    //run for a random string
    printf("%d\n", checkString("AEDZ_value"));

    return 1;
}

int checkString(const char *name)
{
    int i;

    if(!name) return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < N_STRINGS; i++) {
        if (strstr(name, subStrings[i]) != 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }                                                                 

    return -1;
}
```

the function `checkString` would return the index of the prefix.

There are probably though many more effecient implementations for this case.

Comment: `strstr` is strictly worse than `strncmp` for this.

Comment: Also dynamically initializing a mutable global like this is a really bad idea when you could just use static initializers, for several reasons.